# Carothers Chapter 4, Exercise 5

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I'm having some trouble interpreting the following question.

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that $\{x\,:\, f(x) > 0\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\{x\,:\,f(x)=0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

My first response would be something like:

> The set $Y = \{f(x): f(x) > 0\}$ is open because for each $y\in Y$, we can choose $0< \epsilon < y$ so that $B_{\epsilon}(y) \subset Y$. Because $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(Y) = \{x: f(x) > 0\}$ is also open. Similarly, $\{0\}$ is closed and because $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is also closed.

All that said, I'm not sure what $Y$ really means. What if $f(x)$ is some positive constant or if $Y$ is bounded and $\inf\, Y  > 0$? It seems like I should be considering *any* positive functions (as above). In that case, is $Y$ an open subset of a function space?

Answer (score 1):

The proof to your first assertion is not correct. First of all, notice that:

$$X=\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x)>0\}=f^{-1}((0, +\infty))$$ that is, the elements of $X$ are precisely those elements $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)\in (0, +\infty)$.

Since $f$ is continuous you are left to prove $(0, +\infty)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ (recall a function is continuous if and only if the preimage of every open subset is an open subset).

Your second assertion about $\{x: f(x)=0\}$ is correct but you could also see:

$$
\begin{align*}
\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x)=0\}&=\mathbb R\setminus\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x)\neq 0\}\\
&=\mathbb R\setminus(\{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)>0\}\cup \{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)<0\})\\
&=\mathbb R\setminus (f^{-1}(-\infty, 0)\cup f^{-1}(0, +\infty))
\end{align*}
$$
 and since $f^{-1}(-\infty, 0)\cup f^{-1}(0, +\infty)$ is open, its complement is closed.

Comment: Hmm, I deliberately chose $Y$ to be the codomain of the function, which would be $(0, +\infty)$, though I didn't write that out. My main question was whether the continuity of $f$ let us draw conclusions about $\{x\,:\, f(x) > 0\}$ from the codomain of the function or its image, which may or may not be closed or bounded below at some point greater than zero.

Comment: And just to clarify, if the image were closed or a bounded positive interval, then my writing "we can choose $0<\epsilon<y$ so that $B_{\epsilon}(y)\subset Y$" would not be correct ...

Comment: $Y$ is not the codomain of your function, $Y$ is a subset of the domain. The conclusion you can draw is that $\{x: f(x)>0\}$ is open since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: As I wrote it, isn’t it a subset of the codomain? Unless I’m completely wrong on my notation, I thought $Y = \{f(x) : f(x) > 0\}$ was the set of positive values in the codomain.

Comment: I changed the notation for not causing confusion..

Comment: And your set $Y:=\{f(x): f(x)>0\}$ is not open as pointed out by @C. Fujinomiya.

Answer (score 1):

I think the discussion you first responded is wrong since $Y=\{f(x):f(x)>0\}$ you defined is not necessarily open. Generally speaking, if my understanding is not wrong, the $Y$ you defined is $Y=f(\mathbb{R})\cap (0,+\infty)$, and $f(\mathbb{R})$, the image of $f$, is not necessarily open. I hope you can see where is wrong, by looking some specific examples.

Example 1. Let $f(x)=5$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. It is a positive constant function. In this case your $Y=\{f(x):f(x)>0\}$ equals to a point $\{5\}$ and is not open.

Example 2. Let $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Then $f(\mathbb{R})=[-1,1]$, a closed interval between $-1$ and $1$, and $Y=(0,1]$, a left half open interval between $0$ and $1$. So $Y$ is not open.

Comment: Thanks. I think that was the confusion I was having when asking what would happen if $f(x)$ is some positive constant or if $Y$ is bounded and $\inf Y>0$. Based on the answers above, it seems that the domain is $X = f^{-1}(0, +\infty)$, but while $(0, +\infty)$ is open, the image would closed for functions that do not take that entire range of values (e.g., $f(x) = 5$), so it's not clear how to prove that $X$ is open from continuity. Anyways, I'll keep reading to see what I'm missing. Thanks!